Using multiple instances of flutter webview inside a tabview not working as expected
Using flutter I tried to implement a tabbed view containing one webview per tab. Unfortunately the webviews seem not to be isolated properly.
When closing a tab the webview of the closed tab is replacing the webview in the tab next to it.
I created an example which reproduces the behavior.
tab_view.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tabs/web_view.dart';

class TabInfo {
  final String url;
  final Tab tab;
  final WebView detail;

  TabInfo(this.url, this.tab, this.detail);
}

class TabView extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabView({super.key});

  @override
  State<TabView> createState() => _TabViewState();
}

class _TabViewState extends State<TabView>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin, AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<TabView> {
  TabController? _tabController;

  int activeTab = 0;

  var urls = [
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.apple.com",
    "https://www.facebook.com",
    "https://www.microsoft.com",
  ];

  var tabInfos = <TabInfo>[];

  @override
  void setState(fn) {
    if (mounted) {
      super.setState(fn);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _tabController!.dispose();
  }

  Tab createTab(String url) {
    String title = url.replaceFirst("https://", "");
    if (title.length > 20) {
      title = "${title.substring(0, 20)}...";
    }

    return Tab(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Text(title),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  for (var i = 0; i < tabInfos.length; i++) {
                    if (tabInfos[i].url == url) {
                      tabInfos.removeAt(i);
                      break;
                    }
                  }
                  if (activeTab >= tabInfos.length) {
                    activeTab = tabInfos.length - 1;
                  }
                });
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.close,
                color: Colors.white70,
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    print("build tabs");

    // (re-)init the tabInfos when empty
    if (tabInfos.length == 0) {
      for (var url in urls) {
        var tab = createTab(url);
        var webView = WebView(url);
        tabInfos.add(TabInfo(url, tab, webView));
      }

      activeTab = 0;
    }

    for (var info in tabInfos) {
      print("tab info: " + info.detail.url);
    }

    _tabController = TabController(
        length: tabInfos.length, vsync: this, initialIndex: activeTab);

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: TabBar(
              controller: _tabController!,
              tabs: tabInfos.map((e) => e.tab).toList(),
              onTap: (int index) {
                activeTab = index;
              },
            )),
        Expanded(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: tabInfos.map((e) => e.detail).toList(),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}


web_view.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;

  WebView(this.url, {super.key});

  @override
  _WebViewState createState() => _WebViewState();
}

class _WebViewState extends State<WebView>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<WebView> {
  late final WebViewController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("init state " + widget.url);
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(widget.url));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    print("build " + widget.url);

    return Column(children: [
      Padding(child: Text("URL: " + widget.url), padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
      Expanded(
          child: WebViewWidget(
            controller: controller,
          ))
    ]);
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}


I'd expect the tabs not to change their content when a neighbor is closed.

Found a solution, have to use the key parameter when creating a Webview.
